# How to detect if app is in Task View? UWP C#

Tags: c#, uwp

How can i detect if app is in task view in C# (UWP)?

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? The Task View displays all windows, apps aren't "in" it. Do you want to change what gets displayed for your app?

Comment: Yes, if currently it's in Task view state, i want to update UI of my app. How to do it?

Comment: Hello, Task view will display the currently running application, if the UWP application has been launched, then it will be displayed in the Task view. 
But at present, UWP does not provide related APIs for detecting whether the application is in the Task view.